# OpenCV: am I exceeding the matrix size ?

Tags: c++, opencv, for-loop, matrix, size

I have the following code:

```
cv::Mat data ( HEIGHT,WIDTH, CV_32SC1 );
cv::Mat means = cv::Mat::zeros (HEIGHT, WIDTH, CV_64FC1 );
int *dPtr = new int [HEIGHT*WIDTH];
dPtr =  data.ptr<int>();
double *mPtr = new double [HEIGHT*WIDTH];
mPtr =  means.ptr < double>();

for ( int i = 0; i < N; i ++)
{
    for ( int j = 0; j < M; j ++ ) 
    {
         mPtr[ WIDTH * (i-1) + j ] += dPtr[ WIDTH * (i-1) + j ];
    }
}
```

But the program crashes inside the for loop, and I doubt I am somehow exceeding the matrix size. But I cannot figure it out. Could someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are re-assigning the pointers `dPtr` and `mPtr` in the 4th and 6th line, why are  you allocating them in the 3rd and 5th line?

Comment: you are right, I was actually also not writing in that manner, but after asking my problem from my one friend, he told me maybe I should write it in this way. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your indices i,j start with 0 you should omit the -1 in the array expressions (i-1).